# convert dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy in javascript.

Comment: Is it a string you'd like to convert? Provide some code how you initialize the first format.

Comment: are you using the Date() method?

Comment: If this is user input, how do you know it's in one form and not the other?  It may be better to use some sort of a JavaScript date picker.

Comment: Your title and question conflict.  Is it dd/mm/yyyy or dd/ **mon** /yyyy?

Comment: Your heading seems to suggest that you want to convert mon to mm as well exampl MAR to 03

Comment: var date = "09/03/2017>14:28";
var regex = /(\d+)/g;
console.log(date.match(regex));

Answer (score 22):

```
var initial = 'dd/mm/yyyy'.split(/\//);
console.log( [ initial[1], initial[0], initial[2] ].join('/')); //=> 'mm/dd/yyyy'
```

**Edit 2021/05/14**: A snippet using ES20xx

```js
const pad = v => v.padStart(2, `0`);
const initialDate= new Date().toLocaleDateString("nl-NL")
  .split(/[-/]/).map(pad).join("/");
const toFragments = dateString => initialDate
  .split(/[-/]/).map(pad);
const dateTo_mmddyyyy = ([date, month, year], divider = "/") => 
  `${month}${divider}${date}${divider}${year}`;
const [date, month, year] = toFragments(initialDate);
console.log( `initial (dd/mm/yyyy): ${initialDate}`);
console.log( `reformatted to mm/dd/yyyy (array join): ${
  [month, date, year].join('/') }` );
console.log( `reformatted to mm-dd-yyyy (function): ${
  dateTo_mmddyyyy(toFragments(initialDate), "-") }` );
```

Comment: Great solution mate!

Answer (score 20):

```
var date = "24/09/1977";
var datearray = date.split("/");

var newdate = datearray[1] + '/' + datearray[0] + '/' + datearray[2];
```

newdate will contain 09/24/1977.  The split method will split the string wherever it finds a "/", so if the date string was "24/9/1977", it would still work and return 9/24/1977.

Comment: Fast and Easiest way

Answer (score 11):

This is a moment.js version. The library can be found at http://momentjs.com/

```
//specify the date string and the format it's initially in
var mydate = moment('15/11/2000', 'DD/MM/YYYY'); 

//format that date into a different format
moment(mydate).format("MM/DD/YYYY");

//outputs 11/15/2000
```

Answer (score 6):

Convert `dd/mon/yyyy` to `mm/dd/yyyy`:

```
months = {'jan': '01', 'feb': '02', 'mar': '03', 'apr': '04', 'may': '05',
'jun': '06', 'jul': '07', 'aug': '08', 'sep': '09', 'oct': '10', 'nov': '11',
'dec': '12'};

split = 'dd/mon/yyyy'.split('/');
[months[split[1]], split[0], split[2]].join('/');
```

Convert `dd/mm/yyyy` to `mm/dd/yyyy`:

```
split = 'dd/mm/yyyy'.split('/');
[split[1], split[0], split[2]].join('/');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this example where a regular expression is used to find and switch the parts of the string:

```
var d1 = "03/25/2011";
var d2 = d1.replace(/^(\d{1,2}\/)(\d{1,2}\/)(\d{4})$/,"$2$1$3");
alert("d1:"+d1 +"\n d2:"+d2 )

/* 
// OUTPUT

  d1: 03/25/2011
  d2: 25/03/2011

*/
```

EDIT:

I noticed that no other answer is using regular expression and I really wonder why...  :)

Comment: Kinda hack, but the very good quick solution in such a short time. Appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

```
var months = new Array("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec");
var ddSplit = '12/23/2011'.split('/');  //date is mm/dd/yyyy format
alert(ddSplit[1]+'-'+months[ddSplit[0]-1] + '-' + ddSplit[2])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following function specified, 1 date and 2 the date separator (optional)
The date will be returned in the desired format.

```
const setFormatDDMMYYYYtoMMDDYYYY = (date, separator = '/') => {
  const [day, month, year] = date.split('/');
  return month + separator + day + separator + year;
};
```

Comment: An explanation would be helpful, so that people can learn from your answer and not just copy & paste some code from the web. See [answer].

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for me:

```
var fechaLatinFormat= "05-10-2016";//octuber 5, 2016 - octubre 5 del 2016
var datePieces = fechaLatinFormat.split("-"); 
var preFinalDate = new Date(parseInt(datePieces[2]), parseInt(datePieces[1]) - 1, parseInt(datePieces[0]));    
console.log(preFinalDate.format("mm-dd-yyyy"));
```

Or:

```
var fechaLatinFormat= "05-10-2016";//octuber 5, 2016 - octubre 5 del 2016
var datePieces = fechaLatinFormat.split("-"); 
var preFinalDate = [datePieces[1] , datePieces[0] , datePieces[2]];
console.log(preFinalDate.join("-"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = "31/03/2017 14:28";
var regex = /(\d+)/g;
var d = date.match(regex);
var out = d[2] + "-" + d[1] + "-" + d[0] + " " + d[3] + ":" + d[4];
var dag = new Date(out);
console.log(dag);
```

This is only solution for numbers with this regex

Answer (score 0):

```
  var currentDate = new Date()
  var day = currentDate.getDate()
  var month = currentDate.getMonth()
  var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
  document.write("<b>" + month + "/" + day + "/" + year + "</b>")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date = "01/Feb/2010"
monthes = {"Jan": "01", "Feb": "02", "Mar": "03" ... }
date_ar = date.split(/\//)
day = date_ar[0]
year = date_ar[2]
month = monthes[date_ar[1]]
new_date = [month, day, year].join("/")
```

Answer (score 0):

use this function

> 

```
function dateFormat(existingFormat,neededFormat,existingSeperator,newSeperator,dateValue)
{
        var exst    =    existingFormat.toLowerCase().split(existingSeperator);
        var d       =    dateValue.split(existingSeperator);
        d[exst[0]]  =    d[0];  d[exst[1]]=d[1];   d[exst[2]]=d[2];

        var newst    =    neededFormat.toLowerCase().split(existingSeperator);
        newDate      =    d[newst[0]] +newSeperator+d[newst[1]] +newSeperator+d[newst[2]];
        return(newDate); 

}
var dd    =    dateFormat('dd/yy/mm','mm/dd/yy','/','-','30/87/05');//dateFormat(existingFormat,neededFormat,existingSeperator,newSeperator,dateValue)
```

//use same name for date month and year in both formats

You can use this function for converting any format date(including month date year only) to any format. :)