# Renaming files - convert 'yyyyMMdd' to 'MMM-yy' within filename

Tags: regex, date, powershell, filenames

I have a long list of files that all end in a date in the format 'yyyyMMdd' and need to change them to 'MMM-yy'. What would be the best way of going about this?

**e.g.** 'file_one_20120620.pdf' > 'file_one_JUN-12.pdf'

1. Locate 'date' using regex
2. Extract & manipulate date
3. Rename file

Joey suggested a Powershell script below, which looks like it should work, but I keep hitting walls, even when altering the code provided. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can convert the month from number to text with regex alone.

Comment: Sounds dangerous.  What if you had two files, one called 20120620 and one called 20120605?  There would be a collision.  Are your files unique per month-year?

Comment: @nhahtdh - I didn't think I could as I can't pull the text from mid air - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433313/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript - maybe if I can do something similar to the answer from Sylvain Defresne in a VBA function perhaps?

Comment: @RayToal The filenames are all different but they have the same datepart at the end.

Comment: @Bonjour: I think it is possible, but I don't know anything about VBA, so I cannot really help here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with PowerShell:

```
gci | # get files
  foreach {
    $newName = [Regex]::Replace($_.BaseName, '\d{8}$', {
      param($m)
      [datetime]::ParseExact($m.Value, 'yyyyMMdd', $null).ToString('dd-MMM')
    }) + $_.Extension
    Rename-Item $_ $newName
  }
```

Comment: Looks perfect, will try it out now

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, only changes one of the files to '.pdf' and fails for the rest

Comment: Hm; the regex part works correctly (which was what I had most doubts about). You should use `-WhatIf` on the Rename-Item in such cases to prevent data loss, though. I will try in a few minutes whether I can rescue this.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, much appreciated. The additional -WhatIf states that all files will be renamed to .txt (thus the failure). Did you get another chance to look at this as I am racking my brain figuring out the best regex?

Comment: Are you really sure the date always appears at the end and in exactly that format?

Comment: Of course! They're my files produced from Crystal Reports which Datetime parameter can only output in that format (I don't have the SDK to change it unfortunately. I am using a bunch of test files at the moment called 'file_one_20120620.pdf' and so on.

Comment: I think I found a more functional regex which seems to catch my date - '([^\d]|^)\d{8}([^\d]|$)' - but I can't seem to get the replace pattern to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-ChildItem | # get files
foreach {
$newName = [Regex]::Replace($_.BaseName, '\d{8}$', {
  param($m)
  [datetime]::ParseExact($m.Value, 'yyyyMMdd', $null).ToString('dd-MMM')
}) + $_.Extension
Rename-Item $_ $newName -WhatIf
$_
$newname
}
```

This worked with my test list all I did was change gci to get-childItem ..

What if: Performing operation "Rename File" on Target "Item: C:\ab\file_four_20120701.txt Destination: C:\ab\file_four_01-Jul.txt".

What if: Performing operation "Rename File" on Target "Item: C:\ab\file_one_20120620.txt Destination: C:\ab\file_one_20-Jun.txt".

What if: Performing operation "Rename File" on Target "Item: C:\ab\file_three_20120622.txt Destination: C:\ab\file_three_22-Jun.txt".

What if: Performing operation "Rename File" on Target "Item: C:\ab\file_two_20120621.txt Destination: C:\ab\file_two_21-Jun.txt".

Comment: Yeah I honestly can't tell you why it won't work for me. Misplaced or missing library perhaps? Either way, I posted the hacky answer that ended up working for my scenario. Thanks for your input mate.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick for my situation, thanks to [Joey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73070/joey) above.

Based on following file-naming convention:

> 'file_one_20120622.pdf' **converts to** 'file_one_JUN-22.pdf'

```
gci | #get files
  foreach {
    $newDate = [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.Name.Split('_')[2].Split('.')[0],'yyyyMMdd',$null).ToString('MMM-yy').ToUpper()
    $newFilename = $_.Name.Split('_')[0] + '_' + $_.Name.Split('_')[1] + '_' + $newDate + ".pdf"
    Rename-Item $_ $newFilename -WhatIf
  }
```