# Bootstrap data table filter between two date like week to week

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, datatables

I am trying to filter bootstrap data table data with given week date

this example of to gate date of the previous week, current week, next week
https://jsfiddle.net/prtk/znbx32j1/1/

this example for filter data http://plnkr.co/edit/mdeEYoZtnvpfHCdtSxDP?p=preview
and this is the link for I used both examples

JSFiddle for example - https://jsfiddle.net/g90wk05e/1/

the issue with my example is that when you click next or previous week 
this 14/09/2017 and 16/09/2017  date are not filtering it stay on the table.

when I change those two dates it's working but 14/16 not working

and if the date does not find on the table that time also not clear the data table.

HTML

```
<div class="content-left">
  <div class="header-toolbar-list">


    <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-offset-2" id="week-picker-wrapper">
      <label for="week" class="control-label">Select Week</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-rm week-prev">«</button>
        </span>
        <input class="form-control week-picker" placeholder="Select a Week" type="text">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-rm week-next">»</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="taskfilterselector">
      <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">View <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        <li class="selected"><a href="#">Weekly</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Monthly</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>                
  </div>

  <div class="task_wrapper">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <div id="task_list_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6"><div class="dataTables_length" id="task_list_length"><label>Show <select name="task_list_length" aria-controls="task_list" class="form-control input-sm"><option value="10">10</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option></select> entries</label></div></div><div class="col-sm-6"><div id="task_list_filter" class="dataTables_filter"><label>Search:<input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="task_list" type="search"></label></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><table id="task_list" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered dataTable" role="grid" aria-describedby="task_list_info" style="width: 100%;" width="100%" cellspacing="0"> 
        <thead>
          <tr role="row"><th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="task_list" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 49px;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Today 5: activate to sort column descending">Today <div class="task_count">5</div></th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="task_list" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 103px;" aria-label=": activate to sort column ascending"></th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="task_list" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 980px;" aria-label=": activate to sort column ascending"></th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="task_list" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 13px;" aria-label=": activate to sort column ascending"></th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="task_list" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 21px;" aria-label=": activate to sort column ascending"></th></tr>
        </thead> 
        <tfoot>
          <tr><th rowspan="1" colspan="1"></th><th rowspan="1" colspan="1"></th><th rowspan="1" colspan="1"></th><th rowspan="1" colspan="1"></th><th rowspan="1" colspan="1"></th></tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody> 
              <tr role="row" class="odd"> 
              <td class="sorting_1" width="30"><input id="check" type="checkbox"></td> 
              <td width="120">14/09/2017</td>
              <td><span class="taskcategory">Meeting</span><a class="task-name" href="javascript:void(0);">nay</a> <a href="http://secure.seowebcreative.com/edit-task/?id=118"><i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete_post" data-post-id="118"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td> 
              <td width="30"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></td> 
              <td width="30"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>  
            </tr><tr role="row" class="even"> 
              <td class="sorting_1" width="30"><input id="check" type="checkbox"></td> 
              <td width="120">11/09/2017</td>
              <td><span class="taskcategory">Phone</span><a class="task-name" href="javascript:void(0);">goku</a> <a href="http://secure.seowebcreative.com/edit-task/?id=117"><i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete_post" data-post-id="117"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td> 
              <td width="30"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></td> 
              <td width="30"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>  
            </tr><tr role="row" class="odd"> 
              <td class="sorting_1" width="30"><input id="check" type="checkbox"></td> 
              <td width="120">16/09/2017</td>
              <td><span class="taskcategory">Phone</span><a class="task-name" href="javascript:void(0);">test6</a> <a href="http://secure.seowebcreative.com/edit-task/?id=116"><i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete_post" data-post-id="116"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td> 
              <td width="30"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></td> 
              <td width="30"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>  
            </tr><tr role="row" class="even"> 
              <td class="sorting_1" width="30"><input id="check" type="checkbox"></td> 
              <td width="120">05/09/2017</td>
              <td><span class="taskcategory">Meeting</span><a class="task-name" href="javascript:void(0);">test5</a> <a href="http://secure.seowebcreative.com/edit-task/?id=115"><i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete_post" data-post-id="115"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td> 
              <td width="30"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></td> 
              <td width="30"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>  
            </tr><tr role="row" class="odd"> 
              <td class="sorting_1" width="30"><input id="check" type="checkbox"></td> 
              <td width="120">07/09/2017</td>
              <td><span class="taskcategory">Phone</span><a class="task-name" href="javascript:void(0);">test4</a> <a href="http://secure.seowebcreative.com/edit-task/?id=114"><i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete_post" data-post-id="114"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td> 
              <td width="30"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></td> 
              <td width="30"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>  
            </tr><tr role="row" class="even"> 
              <td class="sorting_1" width="30"><input id="check" type="checkbox"></td> 
              <td width="120">01/09/2017</td>
              <td><span class="taskcategory">Phone</span><a class="task-name" href="javascript:void(0);">test3</a> <a href="http://secure.seowebcreative.com/edit-task/?id=113"><i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete_post" data-post-id="113"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td> 
              <td width="30"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></td> 
              <td width="30"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>  
            </tr><tr role="row" class="odd"> 
              <td class="sorting_1" width="30"><input id="check" type="checkbox"></td> 
              <td width="120">09/09/2017</td>
              <td><span class="taskcategory">Phone</span><a class="task-name" href="javascript:void(0);">testu</a> <a href="http://secure.seowebcreative.com/edit-task/?id=112"><i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete_post" data-post-id="112"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td> 
              <td width="30"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></td> 
              <td width="30"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>  
            </tr><tr role="row" class="even"> 
              <td class="sorting_1" width="30"><input id="check" type="checkbox"></td> 
              <td width="120">02/09/2017</td>
              <td><span class="taskcategory">Phone</span><a class="task-name" href="javascript:void(0);">test1</a> <a href="http://secure.seowebcreative.com/edit-task/?id=111"><i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete_post" data-post-id="111"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td> 
              <td width="30"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></td> 
              <td width="30"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>  
            </tr></tbody> 
      </table></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-5"><div class="dataTables_info" id="task_list_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 8 of 8 entries</div></div><div class="col-sm-7"><div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="task_list_paginate"><ul class="pagination"><li class="paginate_button previous disabled" id="task_list_previous"><a href="#" aria-controls="task_list" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0">Previous</a></li><li class="paginate_button active"><a href="#" aria-controls="task_list" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a></li><li class="paginate_button next disabled" id="task_list_next"><a href="#" aria-controls="task_list" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">Next</a></li></ul></div></div></div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js

```
var table = $('#task_list').DataTable();


      var weekpicker, start_date, end_date;

        function set_week_picker(date) {
            start_date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
            end_date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);

            weekpicker.datepicker('update', start_date);
            weekpicker.val( start_date.getDate() + '/' + (start_date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + start_date.getFullYear() + ' - ' + end_date.getDate() + '/' + (end_date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + end_date.getFullYear());

           start_date2 = start_date.getDate() + '/' + (start_date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + start_date.getFullYear();
           end_date2 = end_date.getDate() + '/' + (end_date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + end_date.getFullYear();


        }

        weekpicker = $('.week-picker');
        console.log(weekpicker);
        weekpicker.datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            forceParse: false,
            container: '#week-picker-wrapper',
        }).on("changeDate", function(e) {
            set_week_picker(e.date);

        });
        $('.week-prev').on('click', function() {
            var prev = new Date(start_date.getTime());
            prev.setDate(prev.getDate() - 1);
            set_week_picker(prev);
            table.draw();
        });

        $('.week-next').on('click', function() {
            var next = new Date(end_date.getTime());
            next.setDate(next.getDate() + 1);
            set_week_picker(next);
            table.draw();
        });
        set_week_picker(new Date);

        start_date2 = "";
        end_date2 = "";


        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
          function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
            console.log(data);
              var min = new Date(start_date2).getTime();
              var max = new Date(end_date2).getTime();


                  if (typeof data._date == 'undefined') {

                    data._date = new Date(data[1]).getTime();

                  }
                  //console.log(min+'-'+max+'-'+date_value);
                  console.log(start_date2+'-'+end_date2+'-'+data[1]);
                  if (min && !isNaN(min)) {
                   if (data._date < min) {
                      return false;
                    }
                  }

                  if (max && !isNaN(max)) {
                    if (data._date > max) {
                      return false;
                    }
                  }
                  return true;

          }
      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with the date format. You are using 'dd/mm/yyyy' and javascript is parsing it using 'mm/dd/yyyy' format. Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhinchandran/bp93o3L4/2/). I forked your fiddle and modified it. I changed the assignment of `start_date2` and `end_date2` in `set_week_picker` function and modified datatable function to convert date format (borrowed form [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5433337/2879217)).

Modified parts:

Function `set_week_picker(date)`

`start_date2 = (start_date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + start_date.getDate() + '/' + start_date.getFullYear();
        end_date2 = (end_date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + end_date.getDate() + '/' + end_date.getFullYear();`

Function `.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push`

`data[1] = data[1].split(/\//).reverse().join('/');`

This is not a production ready solution, you need to optimize the code but this will give you the idea.

Comment: hey can you help me with one more thing i stuck with here is the link of my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46129235/select-month-date-range-and-month-using-bootstrap-datepicker