# Select month date range and month using Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, datepicker

How to select a range of month date and month using Bootstrap Datepicker?

I am currently using jQuery UI datepicker to select months and weeks.

here is the example of for week date range i try into convert in month. but getting issue

here is the link for js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/prtk/znbx32j1/1/

html

```
<div class="form-group col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" id="week-picker-wrapper">
    <label for="week" class="control-label">Select Week</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-rm week-prev">&laquo;</button>
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control week-picker" placeholder="Select a Week">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-rm week-next">&raquo;</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
var weekpicker, start_date, end_date;

function set_week_picker(date) {
    start_date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
    end_date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
    weekpicker.datepicker('update', start_date);
    weekpicker.val((start_date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + start_date.getDate() + '/' + start_date.getFullYear() + ' - ' + (end_date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + end_date.getDate() + '/' + end_date.getFullYear());
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    weekpicker = $('.week-picker');
    console.log(weekpicker);
    weekpicker.datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        forceParse: false,
        container: '#week-picker-wrapper',
    }).on("changeDate", function(e) {
        set_week_picker(e.date);
    });
    $('.week-prev').on('click', function() {
        var prev = new Date(start_date.getTime());
        prev.setDate(prev.getDate() - 1);
        set_week_picker(prev);
    });
    $('.week-next').on('click', function() {
        var next = new Date(end_date.getTime());
        next.setDate(next.getDate() + 1);
        set_week_picker(next);
    });
    set_week_picker(new Date);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify `prev` and `next` calculations on `click` events. Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhinchandran/znbx32j1/10/) (Check the console to see the values).

use `setMonth()` and `getMonth()` instead of `setDate()` and `getDate()`. Also you may need to adjust/set the Day value to get accurate results.

Update : This is the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhinchandran/znbx32j1/16/)

Comment: try not but success can you make me fiddle for solution

Comment: there is a fiddle link in the answer

Comment: but it not accurate

Comment: Ok, can you give me an example data. Like what you are expecting as the result?

Comment: previous click (01/08/2017 to 01/09/2017)  
current(01/09/2017 to 01/10/2017)
next click (01/10/2017 to 01/11/2017)

Comment: yay thank you but showing this date 01/08/2017 to 01/09/2017 instead of 01/09/2017 to 01/10/2017 this bcz this is September month so must be display like this 01/09/2017 to 01/10/2017

Comment: i didn't get you, can you explain a little more ?

Comment: i am saying that your example giving me this 01/08/2017 to 01/09/2017 result right now this month is September
so it would be show  01/09/2017 to 01/10/2017 like this