# change the date format for dateRangePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, daterangepicker

I use a dateRangePicker,
it sends me dates in this format "mm-dd-yyyy".

here is my HTML code:

```
<input type="text" name="TextDate" value="10/24/1984" />
```

here is my script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('input[name="TextDate"]').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    minYear: 1901,
    maxYear: parseInt(moment().format('YYYY'),10)
 });
});
</script>
```

I want to make a condition to compare this date to a date in this format "dd-mm-yyyy" in Python.

how can i change the dateRange format to 'dd-mm-yyyy'? please!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433313/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript)

Comment: you are trying to compare 2 dates? let's say mm-dd-yyyy vs dd-mm-yyyy? you can do it without changing the format using new Date()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `dateFormat` option:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('input[name="TextDate"]').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    minYear: 1901,
    maxYear: parseInt(moment().format('YYYY'),10),
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
 });
});
</script>
```

[Here is a link](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate) to possible formats for the `dateFormat` option.