# How to convert static / constant Date to specific format using Javascript

Tags: javascript, date-format

I have this basic javascript that outputs a constant / static date to the console:

```
var TodaysDate ="12/02/2021"; console.log(TodaysDate);
```

The output is simply: 12/02/2021

... Is there a way to get the date to output in the following format: YYYY-MM-DD, without changing the original variable text in the " " to 2021/12/02?
Thanks in advance for any assistance provided.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433313/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple ES6 methods to easily reverse your string

```js
const TodaysDate ="12/02/2021"
const reverseDate = TodaysDate.split("/").reverse().join("/")

console.log(reverseDate)
```

Comment: It is better to mark this as a duplicate rather than answer it.  We don't need yet another Q & A on this topic.